# Is there a way to enter a line break into a long node name in Thinking Space?

Tags: input-methods

When editing a long node name in Free Mind on desktop you can enter a line break by using "shift-enter", then a simple "enter" would confirm the edit.

This same Free Mind mind map when transferred to Android and edited with Thinking Space would display the node with line break correctly. However, I couldn't find a way to enter that line break in Thinking Space. I tried the following input methods: Swype, TouchPal, Hacker's Keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable "Multiline text entry" in the options und "look" (roughly translation from german Localisation). After that you can youst hit enter in the node name.

To confirm the node name then, you have to tap outside of the writing area of the node.

Comment: Perfect answer. Enabled "Multiline text entry" in "Settings" and it does as you described. Marking this answered.